# Email reader support for &mdash;

Tags: email, html-email

Sometimes html does not display correctly in various email readers.

Is it safe to use a long hyphen in html emails?

`&mdash;`

I'm creating the html email using php and sending via a smtp API.

Answer (score 0):

The code for m-dash will work, but depending on the reader it can be a pain to enter correctly. Most readers have a "friendly" UI that assumes you want to see what you are typing, not the rendered result of what you are typing as code.

In many cases, you will have to enter or paste an actual m-dash, and the UI will turn it into code behind the scenes. In others, you will be able to directly edit the HTML.

Comment: I'm creating the html email manually using php and sending via a smtp API. This is a read only question.

Answer (score 0):

replacing `&mdash;` with:

`=?windows-1252?Q?=97?=`

will render an mdash in an email title.